# Excel Formula - Using condition provided in cell itself

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some data in an Excel sheet for which I need to find the minimum among cell range `A4:A10` provided that above output should follow a condition provided in cell `B10`.

Content of cell `B10` is `">10"`

The formula below works for me:

```
=MIN(IF(A4:A10>10,A4:E10))
```

But I need to write a formula that sets the condition by referring to the contents of `B10` (not by directly writing `>10`).
Any help will be great. 
Thanks

Comment: Will your criteria always be "> value of B10" ?

Comment: No ,also please note condition is also written as content

Comment: Then honestly I can't help you unless you allow for filtering. Using advanced filtering you can use such syntax and then you can probably figure something out from there but I'm not sure it's possible in a single function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you could do some changes in sheet like adding criteria headers you could solve it as presented on the picture using the following formula:

```
=DMIN(A3:A10,1,B9:B10)
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is probably the simplest solution that avoids VBA or separating the type and the value of the condition into 2 cells.

Comment: +1 best solution if layout allows for column headings. Otherwise would be more tricky but still possible i think using either: `=MIN(IF(FREQUENCY(1,COUNTIFS(A4:A10,"<="&A4:A10,A4:A10,B10)),A4:A10))` entered normally or `=MIN(SUMIF(OFFSET(A4:A10,ROW(A4:A10)-MIN(ROW(A4:A10)),,1),B10))` array-entered.

Comment: @lori_m, you could add your comment as an answer as it sounds interesting. Thanks for +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this without changing your constraints is to write a short VBA macro you can call after updating `B10`. The code below just builds the formula as a string and passes it to the `.FormulaArray` property of the cell.

```
Sub updateformula()
Dim s1 As Worksheet, condition As String, buildFormula As String
Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1") 'update to match your workbook
condition = s1.Range("B10").Value
buildFormula = "=MIN(IF(A4:A10" & condition & ",A4:E10))"
s1.Range("A11").FormulaArray = buildFormula 'update formula address to match your workbook
End Sub
```

You can either assign a key combination to this macro or place a control button on the sheet to call it after you update `B10`.

Comment: Thanks ,but I need to do it without Macro